# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: asp-classic

I know it is a common error, but I still can't solve it myself.
What I am trying to do is I have a SELECT item called *status* that allow the user to choose their employment status, I want to simply get the result and update the user_table(access file) status cell.
Any reply will be greatly appreciated!

The Code is below:

```vbs
<!--#include file="../conn/conn.asp"-->
<%
id=request.QueryString("id")
status=request.Form("status")
sql="select * from user_table where id="&id
set rs=conn.execute(sql)     
sql="update user_table set Status='"+status+"' where id="&id
'response.Write sql
conn.execute(sql)
conn.close
response.Write "<script>alert('Change Sucessful!');</script>"
set conn=nothing
response.end()
%>
```

Comment: First: so what error are you getting and where? Second: it would probably do you some good to read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection and this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity

Comment: So what's the problem?  And what values are you using for id and status in your tests?  Also, I would recommend using parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Selecting something without doing anything with it is totally meaningless.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your reply! And thank you for reminding me the SQL injection problem, because it is just for myself right now. And the problem turns out I forgot to declare id and link to the database on my previous page.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be having a problem with conn.execute(sql) as well as response.end()

To fix it, you need to do either:

```
conn.execute sql
```

or

```
Call conn.execute(sql)
```

But, yeah, you should follow other comments posted as your technique has security issues. You should consider changing it to use parameters:

```
<!--#include file="../conn/conn.asp"-->
<%

id = request.QueryString("id")
status = request.Form("status")

sql = "select * from user_table where id = @id"
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.CommandText = sql
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.Prepared = True
cmd.Parameters.Refresh 
cmd.Parameters("@id") = id
Set rs = cmd.Execute
Set rs = nothing
Set cmd = nothing

sql = "update user_table set status = @status where id = @id"
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.CommandText = sql
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.Prepared = True
cmd.Parameters.Refresh 
cmd.Parameters("@status") = status
cmd.Parameters("@id") = id
Set rs = cmd.Execute
Set rs = nothing
Set cmd = nothing

response.Write "<script>alert('Change Sucessful!');</script>"
Set conn = nothing
response.end
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing conn.asp leaves conn open? otherwise you need to open it. Also, what shows when you uncomment the response.write sql line?

And, you are definitely opening yourself to hackers. You need to 'clean' anything that comes from a request.form or request.querystring (with at the very least, a `replace(..., "'", "''")`, or much better, use stored procedures instead of straight sql

Comment: "use Stored procedures" is not really the a solution.  `sql = "EXEC spUpdateMyStatus " + status + ", " + id` is still an injection threat.  The solution is to use parameterised queries whether an SP is used or not is immaterial.

Comment: A replace is a very fragile "fix". I don't see any reason not to use parametrized queries in this day and age.

Comment: how is it fragile? (not that I don't believe you, but I'm curious how a hacker can break it)

Comment: A hacker could inject a number, a semicolon and a string for `id` such as `1234; delete from user_table;` wiping your `user_table`. For the `status` they could experiment injecting non English characters such as malformed UTF-8 sequences which will absorb one of your closing quotes to complete the string.